# nodeJS design pattern to break out of a async.waterfall or promise.then.then

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, asynchronous, bluebird

I have 4 async functions to execute in my node app in a waterfall style.

async.waterfall will tidy it up, but based on the result of the first function, I either want to error, carry on down the waterfall or break out to the finished function.

There is no way to do this at the moment (other than 'Error' with a success value, which just smells bad).

I was looking at using promises, (Bluebird), but again, I don't see a way to break out, if I DON'T return another promise in the `.then`, then all  the following `.then`s are executed but with null parameters.

Is there another pattern  / utility that can help?

or am I over thinking this and just call the first method normally , and then based on the result run the async.waterfall, or return the result!

Assuming I have 4 functions to call, a,b,c,d.....

```
async.waterfall([
   function(cb) {
       a("some data", cb)
   },
   function(data, cb) {
        if(data) {
            // HERE we want to skip the remaining waterfall a go to the final func
         } else {
            b("some data", cb);
         }
   },
   c,
   d
],

function(err, data) {
    //do something 
 });
```

Or if they were promises...

```
a("some data")
.then(function(data) {
    if(data) { 
        // here I want to stop executing the rest of the promises...
    } else {
       return b("some data")
    }
})
.then(c)
.then(d)
.catch(function(err) {
    //log error
})
.finally(function() {
     // do something
})
```

I'm thinking I should just do this...

```
function doit(data, done) {
    a("some data", function(err, data) {
       if(err) { return done(err) };
       if(data) { return done(null, data) };

       //Here we run the waterfall if the above doesn't exist.

       async.waterfall([
           function(cb) {
               b("some data", cb)
           },
           c,
           d
        ],
        function(err, data) {
           done(err, data);
        });
}
```

Comment: I think calling `cb` with some specific argument had that effect. But I think that will lead the code to the error branch.

Comment: Yeah, you can do something like `cb("success", data)`, and then check for err=="success" in the final function, but its not a very clean solution...

Answer (score 0):

With promises, you can just attach 'followup promises' to the execution branch that you need:

```
a("some data")
.then(function(data) {
    if(data) { 
        return "foo";//other promises won't be executed here
    } else {
       return b("some data").then(c).then(d)
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    //log error
})
.finally(function() {
     // do something
})
```

Comment: Ah ha!  Couldn't see the wood for the trees!  Thanks.

Comment: @MattBryson you're welcome. Alternatively you can chain promises as in your question and in the handlers check if there is any parameters passed to it and if there are no, just call `return`